# Different Cells in same UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have got a json result, that looks like this:

```
[{
    "EventDate": "2015-02-19",
    "PubEvents": [{
        "Title": "Ladies Night",
        "Description": "Every thursday is Ladies Night at the Irish House.\nLadies: 2 cocktails for the price of 1 - 1 pint of Crowmoor Cider - 30 kr",
        "EventType": "LadiesNight",
        "Start": "2015-02-19",
        "End": "2015-02-20",
        "StartTime": "19:00",
        "EndTime": "02:00",
        "Image": "ladies.jpg"
    }, {
        "Title": "Pat Kelly",
        "Description": "Pat Kelly from Ireland has extensive experience in entertaining all nationalities, as he has travelled around the world from New York to Amsterdam. He has a very wide repertoire maintaining a traditional approach, and is well received and appreciated for his ability to get his audience excited every night he hits the stage. A “sure thing” evening you will get with the talented Pat.",
        "EventType": "Music",
        "Start": "2015-02-19",
        "End": "2015-02-20",
        "StartTime": "21:30",
        "EndTime": "01:00",
        "Image": "http://domain.dk/Images/Musicians/kelly"
    }],
    "Matches": [{
        "EventType": "Sports",
        "Start": "2015-02-19",
        "End": "2015-02-19",
        "StartTime": "18:00",
        "EndTime": "19:00",
        "HomeTeam": {
            "Id": 0,
            "TeamName": "Hold",
            "HomeImageUrl": "defaultHome.png",
            "AwayImageUrl": "defaultAway.png",
            "Badge": "defaultBadge.png"
        },
        "AwayTeam": {
            "Id": 0,
            "TeamName": "AndetHold",
            "HomeImageUrl": "defaultHome.png",
            "AwayImageUrl": "defaultAway.png",
            "Badge": "couldn't get an away team"
        }
    }]
}, {
    "EventDate": "2015-02-20",
    "PubEvents": [{
        "Title": "Pat Kelly",
        "Description": "Pat Kelly from Ireland has extensive experience in entertaining all nationalities, as he has travelled around the world from New York to Amsterdam. He has a very wide repertoire maintaining a traditional approach, and is well received and appreciated for his ability to get his audience excited every night he hits the stage. A “sure thing” evening you will get with the talented Pat.",
        "EventType": "Music",
        "Start": "2015-02-20",
        "End": "2015-02-21",
        "StartTime": "22:30",
        "EndTime": "02:00",
        "Image": "http://domain.dk/Images/Musicians/kelly"
    }],
    "Matches": []
},
```

An Array of Events in the format:

```
var eventDate : String?
var pubEvents : Array<PubEvent>?
var matches : Array<Match>?
```

numberOfSectionsInTableView is eventarray.count, as every date is distinct

numberOfRowsInSection:

```
let event = self.eventarray[section]
let matchesCount = event.matches?.count ?? 0
let pubEventsCount = event.pubEvents?.count ?? 0
return matchesCount + pubEventsCount
```

Since every section has x number of matches and x number of pubEvents i need a combined count of the amount of each.

Here is my problem:

I would need to insert the pubevents (if any) and the matches (if any) in the tableview, but I can't figure it out with Swift.

**Edit**

Philip Mills helped: A very quick implementation:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let event = self.eventarray[indexPath.section] as SortedEvent
        let matchesCount = event.matches?.count ?? 0
        let pubEventsCount = event.pubEvents?.count ?? 0

        if indexPath.row < matchesCount{
            cell.textLabel?.text = "\(event.matches![indexPath.row].homeTeam!.teamName!) v \(event.matches![indexPath.row].awayTeam!.teamName!)"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(event.matches![indexPath.row].startTime!) - \(event.matches![indexPath.row].endTime!)"
        }
        else{
            cell.textLabel?.text = event.pubEvents![indexPath.row - matchesCount].title!
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(event.pubEvents![indexPath.row - matchesCount].startTime!) - \(event.pubEvents![indexPath.row - matchesCount].endTime!)"
        }
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: So, first design your data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're given an index path to provide a cell, see if the row is less than the count of matches.  If it is, use that match. If it's not less, subtract the count of matches from the row and use that as the index of the pub event you want.

Comment: how would I get the count of matches in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: You get an index path that contains a section and you already have code: `let event = self.eventarray[section]
let matchesCount = event.matches?.count ?? 0`

Comment: Fantastic. Problem was I thought the indexpath was linear from 0 to eventcount - the fact that it starts at 0 at each section helped a lot :) (doh)

Thank you sir